# Creating User using Djoser is not storing data for all fields (

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-registration, djoser

I am using DRF to create a ReST API.

I am using Djoser for user management. I am using the default django user model as it serves my purpose.

When I hit the endpoint to register new user, only username, password and email are getting stored. I am passing all data like first_name, last_name and is_staff but only username, password and email are being stored.

I have attached Djsoer settings.

```
DJOSER = {
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': '#/password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'USERNAME_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': '#/username/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'ACTIVATION_URL': '#/activate/{uid}/{token}',
    'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL': True,
    'PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
    'USERNAME_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
    'USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True, #Designed to propote good programming practice
    'SET_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True, #Designed to propote good programming practice
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_RETYPE': True, #Designed to propote good programming practice
    'LOGOUT_ON_PASSWORD_CHANGE' : True, #Note : Logout only works with token based authentication. djoser 2.10
    'PASSWORD_RESET_SHOW_EMAIL_NOT_FOUND': False, #Please note that setting this to True will expose information whether an email is registered in the system
    'USERNAME_RESET_SHOW_EMAIL_NOT_FOUND': False, #Please note that setting this to True will expose information whether an email is registered in the system
    'token': 'djoser.serializers.TokenSerializer',
    'token_create': 'djoser.serializers.TokenCreateSerializer',
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Djoser but You can use python package  **django-allauth** 
from https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

In django-allauth you can add first_name and last_name and many other information like this

[django-allauth features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14nnn.png)

Or if you specifically want to add    *first_name, last_name and is_staff and any other personal information*  then you can create particular model about this user's information in

**models.py**

Comment: I had looked into django-allauth but the problem with django-allauth package is that it doesn't provide ReST endpoints.